# Tkinter program that prints the entire window on a printer

Tags: python, tkinter, printing

I am writing a Python3 program on Raspberry Pi 3B +.
I use Tkinter for the GUI.

Now, I want to write a program that prints the entire window on a printer by pressing a button on the window.
I have already installed CUP and can print with other standard applications.

The program is as follows, but an error message appears when the button is pressed.
What should I do now?

Error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File “/usr/lib/python3.y/tkinter/__init__.py”, Line 1705, in __call__
  return　self.func(゛args)
 File　"/home/pi/Projects/tk.py", line　19, in　printer
   img.save(buf, 'PNG’)
 Fi!e　"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PlL/lmage・pｙ”, line　1994, in save･
   save_handler(self, fp, filename
  File　"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py" ，line　773, in _save
   fp.write(_MAGIC)
  TypeError: string argument expected, 90t 'bytes'
```

Source code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*- coding: utf8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import subprocess
from PIL import Image
import io

def printer():
    buf = io.StringIO()
    screen = (500, 500)
    bgcolor = (0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
    img = Image.new('RGB', screen, bgcolor)
    img.save(buf, 'PNG')
    p = subprocess.Popen('lp', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate(buf.getvalue())
    p.stdin.close()
    buf.close()

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-type','splash')
root.geometry("800x480")
button = tk.Button(root,text="閉じる",command=sys.exit)
button.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(root,text="印刷",command=printer)
button2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: instead of `io.StringIO()`, try `io.BytesIO()`...

Comment: The first argument to [`Image.save()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) function is supposed to be a filename string, not the image's data. The latter is whatever the image has in it at that point. In the code in your question this is an all-black 500x500 image when the call is made.

Comment: The first argument of `Image.save()` can be either a filename or file object.  `buf` is a file object.  OP wants to save the image data to the string buffer and then pass to the command `lp`.

Comment: ***"TypeError: string argument expected"***: Works for me using `io.BytesIO()`, according the docu **"be opened in binary mode."** [PIL.Image.Image.save](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save)

Comment: Thank you for your  comments.
 I rewrite 'io.StringIO()' to 'io.BytesIO()'.
The error message is not appear. The output message is "request ID: xxxxx(0 file)" which is Japanese version.
The printer works and put an almost black paper out. I need the picture of window with two bottons which showed on display.
 I rewrite 'screen=(800,400)' to 'screen=(800,480)'. Because, I notice 'root.geometry("800x480")'. But, the result is same.
What should I do?

Comment: Your code created a black image of size specified by `screen` and passed this image to `lp` command.  If you want to print the program window, try using `PIL.ImageGrab` to grab the screen shot of the program window and print the screen shot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.
After that, I changed my code.
I used 'io.BytesIO()' and 'pyautogui.screenshot'.
My problem is almost solved, but it isn't perfectly.
To make a long story short, the code work correctly  on Thonny IDE and it doesn't work  on LXterminal.
It is difficult to explain that. so, I will post the another question with  my new code.

Comment: @hibari ***"doesn't work on LXterminal."***: Read up on [screenshot-functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#screenshot-functions), about the rquirements using `X`.